# Unused webspace as cloud storage

Tags: cloud-hosting, personal-website, storage

One of the websites I maintain has 50GB storage but the website uses under 100MB and will not increase in size significantly. Would there be any problem isn using 10GB for independent cloud storage for file, documents etc.? 
I can see no problems but would like to check first.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking us? We're not your host. But, this shouldn't be an issue. As long as you don't village their tells of services with your content they probably don't care either.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, I will double check with ISP tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what problems you envisage, so I will assume you are not asking whether it is a technical issue, rather whether you are allowed.

It will 100% depend on the terms and conditions of your host.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Steve. It is such an obvious use of unused space that I am surprised I have never seen it suggested so wondered if there was a technical problem I was not able to see. The ISP already installs a public_ftp folder so I assume  it is legal but maybe I should check that as well.